# Problems with taking input from stdin - Invalid read/write from valgrind

Tags: c, io, stdin, fgets, scanf

I ran valgrind on a program I'm working on and I'm getting the following errors - I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated ahead of time. Let me know if you need any more information

```
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4EB9390: __GI___rawmemchr (rawmemchr.S:25)
==27928==    by 0x4EA514F: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:45)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D64: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:42)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4C2B834: __GI___rawmemchr (mc_replace_strmem.c:1110)
==27928==    by 0x4EA514F: _IO_str_init_static_internal (strops.c:45)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D64: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:42)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb041 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4E7D920: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:620)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D79: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:44)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4EA36D2: _IO_sputbackc (genops.c:731)
==27928==    by 0x4E7D97B: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:625)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D79: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:44)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4E7DC7D: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1394)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D79: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:44)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4E7E9EF: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1781)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D79: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:44)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb041 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
==27928== Invalid read of size 1
==27928==    at 0x4EA36D2: _IO_sputbackc (genops.c:731)
==27928==    by 0x4E7DDF3: _IO_vfscanf (vfscanf.c:1811)
==27928==    by 0x4E86D79: __isoc99_vsscanf (isoc99_vsscanf.c:44)
==27928==    by 0x4E86CF7: __isoc99_sscanf (isoc99_sscanf.c:33)
==27928==    by 0x401A76: countAndSort (lab1.c:442)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==  Address 0x55bb041 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 10,000,000 free'd
==27928==    at 0x4C27D4E: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:427)
==27928==    by 0x4019D6: countAndSort (lab1.c:430)
==27928==    by 0x4014EB: doProcess (lab1.c:316)
==27928==    by 0x4011C2: main (lab1.c:211)
==27928==
```

Regardless of what you might think from the origin of each error, through lots of trial and error, commenting out/back in blocks of code and separately testing pieces of code in test compilations, I've found that the following is the erroneous source. If I comment this code out in my program, all errors go away.

NOTE: integers is a global int* type. countToUse is a global int type. The goal of the code here is to read all integers from stdin and get them into a correctly sized dynamic array.

```c
            // Load stdin into a buffer
            char *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
            if(buffer == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc for stdin buffer in countAndSort() failed. Exiting.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            if (fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error loading input from stdin into buffer. Exiting.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            // Get a count of the numbers to create the array
            int count = 0;
            int index = 0;
            int num, delta;
            while (index < BUFFER_SIZE && sscanf(&buffer[index], "%d%n", &num, &delta) == 1){
                    count++;
                    index += delta;
            }

            // Initialize the array with the proper size
            integers = malloc(count*sizeof(int));
            if(integers == NULL){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc for integer array in countAndSort() failed. Exiting. \n");
                    exit(1);
            }

            // Load the integers into the array
            index = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
// LINE 442 IS RIGHT BELOW THIS LINE ------------------------------------
                    if (index < BUFFER_SIZE && sscanf(&buffer[index], "%d%n", &integers[i], &delta) != 1){
                            fprintf(stderr, "There was a problem reading the buffer!\n");
                            exit(1);
                    }
                    index += delta;
            }

            if(buffer != NULL)
                    free(buffer);

            countToUse = count;
```

Comment: Where is `doProcess()`

Comment: @Cyclone It's not caused by doProcess. I've already ruled that out. doProcess (at line 323) calls the function that contains this code (countAndSort).

Comment: @Cyclone Line 323 in count process reads "countAndSort()"

Comment: this is too large `char buffer[10000000];`, you can `malloc()` it you are overflowing the stack. There is a limit for the stack which I think is `8388608`, try with `ulimit -s` and multiply that number by `1024`.

Comment: and which line is line 380?

Comment: @iharob I just changed it to allocate memory in the heap. Thanks for that catch

Comment: @iharob No, it solved a couple errors but I'm still getting a whole list originating from the same piece of code. Invalid read/writes. They are all of the same error type so I only posted two in the question

Comment: I doubt that `index > 10000000` but you don't check for that.

Comment: @iharob: The stack size in C is implementation-defined. Not only that, but it can differ between different *threads* in the same program. But yes, stack in C is typically tiny, compared to the heap.

Comment: There is no stack size in c, it's OS defined and the OP is apparently using linux which makes me think that `ulimit -s` will return `8M` if the OP didn't tweek that.

Comment: @iharob I've updated the question with the errors i'm getting right now

Comment: Just check `index < 10000000` before any of the `sscanf()`'s. I am curious about the file contents, can you send it to me? is it larger thatn `~9M`? iharob@gmail.com

Comment: @iharob: Well, yes, strictly speaking. But it is *typically* implemented as a memory region somewhere in the process, and its size can vary even between two executions of the same program.

Comment: this `char *buffer = malloc(MAX_INTEGERS * sizeof(int));` is wrong, be cause you need the size of the type of the pointer so `char *buffer = malloc(MAX_INTEGERS * sizeof(*buffer));` which is the same as `char *buffer = malloc(MAX_INTEGERS * sizeof(char));` and since `sizeof(char) == 1` then `char *buffer = malloc(MAX_INTEGERS);`. But this is not the problem, it's just allocating `4` times more memory.

Comment: @iharob I was thinking about that earlier but if i do that and someone enters in an integer that is more than 1 digit, it would take up 2 bytes, would it not? So the buffer would not, in reality, be big enough to hold MAX_INTEGERS (defined as 1,000,000). That was my previous code, for some reason I think i copy pasted it by accident, but I've just updated it with the changes you suggested and I am now allocating the buffer in the heap with 10mb

Comment: valgrind is complaining that nobody wrote to the first byte of some 4mb buffer. You dont have a 4mb buffer in what you show, can you please fix it so that the code and valgrind output match and can we have line numbers please - or at least highlight the lines vg is moaingin about

Comment: @JayB: given the problem you're having (which seems similar to a nearly duplicate question that you have deleted), I think you should work on a simple program that just reads your data file/`stdin` into a buffer, converting the data as you might need. That way you can post a complete example program that shows the problem (also indicate what your input data format is). It looks like your fundamental problem is reading the input data into a buffer without overrunning the allocated memory. Once you have that single problem successfully solved, you can drop it into your larger program.

Comment: @pm100 Done. I added a comment where line 442 is.  That seems to be the source of the problem from the current errors. Also, the buffer is 10mb.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks. I deleted my previous questions because it was incorrectly referencing another piece of code. I actually have the code in a separate testing file right now but It's giving me the same errors. Line 442 is definitely the cause, but I don't know whats wrong with it.

Comment: you free buffer10 lines above this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are not reading beyond the bounds of `buffer`, like this

```
while ((index < 10000000) && (sscanf(&buffer[index], "%d%n", &num, &delta) == 1))
```

and the same applies for all the `buffer[index]`'s.

Also, from the error it seems that you have `free()`d `buffer` and then attempted to read from it.

Comment: I've made these changes and the same errors still remain